# Loading partial with Angular directives not rendering the second time the view is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am buulding an app using ionic framework. I wonder this is more of an AngularJS issuse rather than ionic issuse.

I have following states under main abstract app state.

```
       app.state('app.a', {
                url: "/a",
                views: {
                    "mainContent": {
                        templateUrl: "app/views/a.html"
                    }
                }

            }).state('app.b', {
                url: "/b",
                views: {
                    "mainContent": {
                        templateUrl: "app/views/b.html"
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have a directive to load partial as following.

```
app.directive('widthLengthLoadSpeed', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            id: '=id'
        },
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/width.length.load.speed.htm.html'
    }
})
```

On a.html I have  a button which has ng-click to a function which has following code.

```
angular
.element(document
  .getElementsByClassName("widthLengthLoadSpeedBeforethis"))
        .prepend(
      $compile('<width-length-load-speed id="StraightRunning_'+$scope.$id+'">
               </width-length-load-speed>')($scope));

    if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' &&
        $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
         $scope.$apply();
```

and on b.html the button is linked to function with the code.

```
angular
    .element(document
      .getElementsByClassName("widthLengthLoadSpeedBeforethis"))
            .prepend(
          $compile('<width-length-load-speed id="circular_'+$scope.$id+'">
                   </width-length-load-speed>')($scope));

        if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' &&
            $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
             $scope.$apply();
```

The views are loaded correctly with partials when I click the button on a.html and go to b.html and viceversa. However, the view doesn't load the partial when I go back and click button on one the pages that I have already been after being  on another page. I can see the html in the element though while debugging. I am banging on the this the whole day. Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to insert stuff in the DOM this way? Ionic caches views, this might mess with things.

Comment: @KjellIvar that partial view is optional and it should be rendered based on input. Cannot render them when the page is loaded.

Comment: use `ng-if` for conditional... no need to inject your own html into dom and really no need for element ID in angular either

Comment: @charlietfl and Kjell thanks guys. It was not the best way to use Angular:trying to insert HTML. I refactored with ng-if with flags being set using JS instead. The code just did't work, it flew :D Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views are conflicting each other due to caching.

[Disable cache](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) with an attribute `cache-view = false`.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Well, not exactly the answer I was looking for but this solves the issue. Thanks.